# How to weight on tag for showing different element on each visit?

Tags: php, html, weighted

I need to create a function for one page I'm working on.

I have a `div` which I've a `H1` tag & `IMG` tag inside. I don't want to show them both tags at same time in this `div` on each visit. So I was wondering if there possible to have a sort of *weight/show-rate* on this `div` for the `h1` tag & `img` tag.

So for instance *30%* of the time, I show a text `<h1>Text here</h1>` while *70%* of the time show `<img src="example.png">`.

The rates doesn't need to be 100% accurate, but as long as `img` tag is showing most of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [mt_rand](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_mt_rand.asp) to generate a random number between 1 and 100.

```
<?php if(mt_rand(1, 100) <= 30): ?>
    <h1>My text</h1>
<?php else: ?>
    <img src="myimage.png" alt="my image's alt">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rand function to get a 30% of times a variable set to true, and then depending on that variable show the h1 or the img

http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php

```
<div>
<?php
  if (rand(0, 100) <= 30){
    echo "<h1>...</h1>";
  }
  else{
    echo "<img... />";
  }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array of 100 elements and have 30 with the H1 and 70 with img. Then just randomly pick an element on each load, maybe with rand().

There's probably better solutions :-)

Comment: This would not be a good practice as looks like and very messy. But thanks anyway @martin

Comment: This is a very ineficient and complicated way to get a % random value!!